# What is the benefit to share a singleton Unity container in Global.aspx?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I read the article about using Unity in Asp.Net.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2008/07/01/how-to-use-unity-container-in-aspnet/
His ideas is building the container in Global.asax and access the container via HttpContext.

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : Page where T : class
{
    protected override void  OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var accessor = context.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
        var container = accessor.Container;
        container.BuildUp(this as T);

        base.OnPreInit(e);

    }


. . .
```

My question is: What is the benefit to share a singleton Unity container in Global.aspx?
Can I build the container in the BasePage? Like this:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : Page where T : class 
{
    protected override void  OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    { 
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddNewExtension<MyUnityContainerExtension>();
        container.BuildUp(this as T);

        base.OnPreInit(e);

   }

. . .
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you build up the container in the `OnPreInit` event of the page, this means that you create a new container instance on each request. There is a lot of overhead when creating a container instance per request and this can slow down your web application considerably. The Unity container (or any DI container for that matter) is optimized to have a single instance per AppDomain.